# Python Program, while loop not executing?

Tags: python

```
Names=[0,1,2,3,4]
Names[1]=='Ben'
Names[2]=='Thor'
Names[3]=='Zoe'
Names[4]=='Katie'
Max=4
Current=1
Found=False
PlayerName=input('What player are you looking for?')
while Found==False and Current==Max:
    if Names[Current]==PlayerName:
        Found=True

    else:
        Current+=1


if Found==True:
    print('Yes, they have a top score')
else:
    print('No, they do not have a top score')
```

This is the program. When any of the 4 names at the top are entered, the program should print, 'Yes, they have a top score', but when anything else is entered it should print,'No, they do not have a top score'.

However whatever name is entered it returns the 'No, they do not have a top score' message. I think it may have something to do with the loop but not sure what.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your second condition is inverted. You want

```
while Found==False and Current!=Max:
```

That said, in Python you can do this much more simply using the `in` operator:

```
names = ['Ben', 'Thor', 'Zoe', 'Katie']
player_name = input('What player are you looking for?')

if player_name in names:
    print('Yes, they have a top score')
else:
    print('No, they do not have a top score')
```

That way, you don't need the `while` loop at all.

Comment: Thanks, it was just the "current!=max:" that was the problem. Silly mistake.

Comment: As others have pointed out, there are plenty of logical errors besides that one.

Comment: This seems like a very 'pythonic' way of doing this. Great answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
Names[1]=='Ben'
...
```

Is not assignment, it is equality check (and it returns `False`, although this is irrelevant)

Hence, your list is not modified, and names are checked against the list `[0,1,2,3,4]`, and they never match, which is not a surprise.

Additionally, your loop condition is incorrect, and the code there is never run.

You should however consider writing your program is a more pythonic way, using the `in` operator, as suggested above, or a least using a `for` loop, iterating over your list.

Answer (score 1):

In your `while` loop, you're doing these comparisons:

```
Found==False and Current==Max
```

The second part of the condition will never evaluate to `True` because `Current` is always set to `1` before the loop, which is `!=` to `Max` - therefore, the code in the loop never evaluates.

Answer (score 1):

Look here:

```
Names=[0,1,2,3,4]
Names[1]=='Ben'
Names[2]=='Thor'
Names[3]=='Zoe'
Names[4]=='Katie'
```

This doesn't do what you think it does. Afterwards, `Names` is equal to `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`. The next few lines don't assign names to `Names` but only check whether an element is equal to a name. For example, `Names[1]=='Ben'` checks if the second element in `Names` is equal to `Ben` (so this evaluates to `True` or `False`) but nothing is done with the result.

Answer (score 1):

Your code never enters inside while loop, because initially Current = 1 and Max = 4, so they are not equal.

Answer (score 1):

Do you try to program BASIC in Python? :-)

Others have answered why it does not work. Even if you do these changes, your program does look more like BASIC than like Python.

You should do the following:

1. Use index 0 as well. You allocate 0..4 and use 1..4. Just use 0..3.
2. iterate through a list with `for item in listobject:` instead of the while loop.
3. Don't do `if Found==True:`, just use `if Found:`
4. Don't name your variables with starting uppercase - these names are for classes. Use `found` instead of `Found`.